# How to copy NgTemplate and NgTemplate Outlet with Inheritance or something else in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

We have a Component with Typescript business logic, and then Html formatting.
The marketing department wants to create a different html format/orientation,  with Same Business logic.

To extend the Same business Typescript logic, we are utilizing Inheritance and `extends` as quick and easy way.

For html formatting, say Div A, Div B, Div C, will be arranged in different orders and formats, with some additional changes .
We have NgTemplate and NgTemplateOutlets for each Div defined in the original Component.

When trying to invoke utilize the ngTemplate Outlets in the inheritance component, we are noticing they are not showing.

Question is, how do I share ng-template Outlets to the new Inheritance Component?

**Original Typescript**

```
export class OriginalClass {
```

**Original Component html:**

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet = "templateref1"></ng-container>
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet = "templateref2"></ng-container>

// they are defined in bottom of html here
<ng-template #templateref1>
    hello
<ng-template>
<ng-template #templateref1>
    hello2
<ng-template>
```

**New Typescript class Inheritance :**

```
export class NewClass extends OriginalClass {
```

**New Component html: trying to call ng-templates without redefining them**

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet = "templateref2"></ng-container>
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet = "templateref1"></ng-container>
```

Comment: can you create a demo , how did you inherit the original component template 

Comment: Everyone who asks this same question has some hacky solution they're struggling to get working. Place your common *business logic* into an Angular library, and then start a new Angular application that needs custom Html. Keep doing this process until you have lots of shareable libraries. If that sounds like a lot of work it's because it is a lot of work, and everyone wants some clever short cut. I've been hired many times to try and salvage projects done the way you're doing it. You're over thinking the solution to a problem that doesn't really exist. You're creating it.

Comment: hi @MuhammedAlbarmavi  I didn't that what we're trying to figure out, we inherit the typescript with this export class NewClass extends OriginalClass {